# Problems with legend in conversion from ggplot to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have problem with legend in ggplotly. This is little example of what I mean:

```
library(reshape2) # for melt 
df <- melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2"))
    p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
    p2 <- p1 + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "LEFT", title.position = "left")) p2
    ggplotly(p2)
```

I created more complicated ggplot and I chnged my legend a lot. In ggplotly I can not see any of my changes.

Many thanks!

Comment: you can try to play with the margin. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432124/x-axis-gets-hidden-in-plotly-r/36432698#36432698

Answer (score 0):

As `MLavoie` says, you can try to extend the margins (https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-margin):

```
library(reshape2) # for melt 
df <- melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2")) 
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
p2 <- p1 + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "LEFT", title.position = "left")) 
ggplotly(p2) %>% layout(margin=list(r=120))
```